# How to create day/Time counter on specific field update

Tags: workflow, opportunity, custom-field, business-logic

I have a pick list field in opportunity object name “Opportunity status”. There are two values in this field Hold and Un-Hold. I want, when I do select hold  another field name "Hold duration" start counting days. As soon as I un-hold the status it should stop to count days. So we can get to know for how many days this opportunity was on hold.
Please help and advice how I can achieve this. I don’t want to add it in standard stage pick list.

Comment: Are you expecting the time to be dynamically populated even before the status is changed to Un-Hold?  Ex: Now, it is changed to Hold.  After 2 days, still is in Hold, do you expect the Hold duration to show 2 days? or Hold Duration to be populated only after it is changed to Un-Hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want *two* `Date` fields if you don't want to keep counting once you un-hold.

1. Create a Datetime field called `Hold Start`. Populate it with a workflow rule.
   Criteria: `AND(ISCHANGED(Status__c), Status__c = "Hold")`
   Value: `NOW()`
2. Create a Datetime field called `Hold End`. Populate it with a workflow rule.
   Criteria: `AND(ISCHANGED(Status__c), Status__c = "Un-hold")`
   Value: `NOW()`
3. Create a formula field called `Hold Duration` of type `Number`.
   Value: `IF(Status__c = "Un-hold", TODAY - DATEVALUE(Hold_Start__c), DATEVALUE(Hold_End__c) - DATEVALUE(Hold_Start__c))`

I recommend `Datetime` because you get more precision, but you could certainly use `Date` fields instead and remove the formula's calls to `DATEVALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

Create date field on Opportunity which will store the date when Opportunity status field value is updated to "Hold". Write a workflow which will update this field to current date/time when Opportunity becomes hold. Create a formula field to count the difference between the new date field and today. The difference will give you the number of days the Opportunity was idle.